# IAsyncOperation<BitmapImage>^

Tags: c++, asynchronous, windows-store-apps, iasyncresult, iasyncoperation

Im trying to create a C++ Runtime compoment to use in c# windows store app project;

I Created a new project C++ -> Windows Store App -> Windows Runtime Component.
The new project has default class1.

This is what i m trying to do and i get error:

Class1.h:

```
public ref class Class1 sealed
{
public:
    Class1();
            Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::BitmapImage^>^ StreamToBitmap(Windows::Storage::Streams::IRandomAccessStream^ fileStream);

};
```

Class1.cpp:

```
Class1::Class1()
{
}



IAsyncOperation<BitmapImage^>^ StreamToBitmap(IRandomAccessStream^ fileStream)
{
    return create_async([=]()
    {
        auto bitmapImage = ref new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage->SetSource(fileStream);
        return bitmapImage;

    });

}
```

Error

> Error 2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation ^ **cdecl TestRuntimeC_*toCS::Class1::[TestRuntimeC*_toCS::_*IClass1PublicNonVirtuals]::LoadImage(struct Windows::Storage::Streams::IRandomAccessStream ^)" (?LoadImage@?Q*_IClass1PublicNonVirtuals@TestRuntimeC__toCS@@Class1@2@U$AAAP$AAU?$IAsyncOperation@P$AAVBitmapImage@Imaging@Media@Xaml@UI@Windows@@@Foundation@Windows@@P$AAUIRandomAccessStream@Streams@Storage@6@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual long _*stdcall TestRuntimeC*_toCS::Class1::[TestRuntimeC_*toCS::*_IClass1PublicNonVirtuals]::__abi_TestRuntimeC__toCS***IClass1PublicNonVirtuals***_abi_LoadImage(struct Windows::Storage::Streams::IRandomAccessStream ^,struct Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation ^ *)" (?__abi_TestRuntimeC__toCS***IClass1PublicNonVirtuals*___abi_LoadImage@?Q_*IClass1PublicNonVirtuals@TestRuntimeC*_toCS@@Class1@2@U$AAGJP$AAUIRandomAccessStream@Streams@Storage@Windows@@PAP$AAU?$IAsyncOperation@P$AAVBitmapImage@Imaging@Media@Xaml@UI@Windows@@@Foundation@7@@Z)    C:\Users\Stamatis\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestRuntimeC++toCS\TestRuntimeC++toCS\Class1.obj    TestRuntimeC++toCS

Comment: Do you have `LoadImage` anywhere in your code?

Comment: No not yet. I will call it from a c# project but i cant complile this one.

Comment: Well, the code seems to be complaining about the missing `LoadImage`  implementation, so I thought that's what's missing.

Comment: So I m missing some include?Any ideas what I need? btw if i put it in private it work but i need public so i can call.Thanks and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Not sure. Just trying to parse that error message. It seems like maybe there is a `LoadImage()` method declared in some header file in your solution, but not implemented anywhere. Then again maybe it's just that something doesn't like the `++` in your project path.